# Google Scripts and Original Filename

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

In the Google API [reference files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files), there is an originalFilename field.  In the Google Scripts api, there doesn't seem to be a method for accessing this field; there's a getName() method, but no getoriginalFilename method.

Can I implement this method in the Google scripts API?  Or is this something I'd have to do in offline code?

This is the code snippet in question.  Ideally, I'd like a file.getOriginalName() method instead of file.getName() method.

```
var file;
while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    data = [file.getName(),
            file.getDateCreated(),
            file.getUrl(),
            "docs.google.com/…" + file.getId()];
```

Comment: Did you try getOriginalFilename?

Comment: I did (tried getOriginalFilename and getoriginalFilename) - no luck there.  Error message reads: TypeError: Cannot find function getOriginalFilename in object .

Comment: Can you include the code you are using that works for getName() and not getOriginalFilename()?

Comment: Yup, added to original post.

Comment: My app sheet skills are a bit rusty having the code in the question should help you get an answer.  Unfortunately i cant help anymore.

Comment: @snark17 Unfortunately, there are no methods for retrieving ``originalFilename`` in Class DriveApp. So although I'm not sure whether this is what you want, for example, how about using Drive API of [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)? By this, you can retrieve ``originalFilename``. I think that there are 2 patterns. 1. ``Drive.Files.get(fileId).originalFilename``. 2. ``Drive.Files.list().items[].originalFilename``.